# Unable to find rails association Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model-associations

I am attempting to do a query via a junction table, though Rails is given me the below error

[image]

Venue Model

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base


attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude, :name, :phone, :suburb, :state, :country
  after_validation :geocode

  has_many :orders, through: :venues_orders

  geocoded_by :full_address


  def full_address
    [address, suburb, state, country].compact.join(', ')
  end

end
```

Order Model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :fulfilled, :item, :placed, :person_id, :special_instructions, :priority, :flag, :milk

  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :venue
```

Venues Orders Model

```
class VenuesOrders < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :order_id, :venue_id
end
```

Comment: You're association is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders, through: :venues_orders
  has_many :venues_orders   

end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :venues, through: :venues_orders
  has_many :venues_orders   

end

class VenuesOrders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :order
end
```

For more details read : [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Another advice: The convention for creating a `join table` is lexical ordering. Like, `OrdersVenues` not `VenuesOrders`

Comment: thanks, I've rolled back the model and recreated to use lexical ordering

Comment: still getting the same warning message